# Homology group of sphere relative to the complement of finitely many points

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cw-complexes

Let $X=S^n, n>0$ and $A\subseteq X$ such that $X\setminus A$ contains finitely many points $x_1,...,x_m$. I need to show that the reduced homology $H_n(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}^m$.

I need to do this particularly by constructing a CW-complex on $X$, and not using anything fancy like excision. I tried many things and am utterly confused as to how to approach this.

If we take every point not in $A$ to be 0-cells, would $A$ be a CW-complex with no zero cells? How would I compute $H_i(A)$ as I don't know whether or not $A$ is a CW-complex (which prevents me form using the LES for relative homology). Hatcher doesn't have any helpful information on this problem.

In the case $n=1, m=2$, $X=S^1$ is a circle, and we take $x_1,x_2$ as the 0-cells, along with 2 arcs as 1-cells. Then $A$ is the disjoint union of 2 copies of $int D^1$ (ie. line segments). Is $A$ a CW-complex? Does $H_0(A)$ vanish in this case (since A has no 0-cells)? It shouldn't as then the LES would yield $H_1(X,A)=\mathbb{Z}$, and not $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Can anyone please help me as to which CW complex on $X$ is needed? Appreciate it!

Comment: Why do you need to know if $A$ is a CW-complex to use LES for relative homology? The LES works for any topological pair $(X, A)$.

Comment: I need to compute $H_i(A)$ as that is involved in the les.

Comment: The space $A$ is just $S^n$ with finitely many points deleted (say $k$). Then you can take stereographic projection about one of those points to get $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $(k-1)$ points deleted, which deformation retracts to wedge sum of $(k-1)$ copies of $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I want to ask for example why is $(0,1)$ not a CW complex with a single 1-cell and no 0-cells? How does it fail the definition of a Cw complex? I know that its 0th homology doesn't vanish as it deformation retracts to a point.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to the question, but the CW complexes are built by attaching closed disks $D^n$

Comment: We define $H_i$ with the chain complex consisting of free abelian groups generated by the cells of each dimension. I guess is it true the Cw complexes must have 0-cells?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143193/discussion-between-hlcrypto123-and-feynhat).

Comment: Every CW complex has at least one $0$ dimensional cell by definition. It does not have to have higher dimensional cells (can have gaps), but dimension $0$ is mandatory.

Comment: Also CW complexes arise by attaching closed cells of higher and higher dimension, starting from discrete space (the $0$ cells). Closed cells are compact. And therefore you can imagine (which is actually true) that glueing finitely many compact spaces remains compact. And so $(0,1)$ interval cannot be represented by finitely many cells. But indeed, it is a CW complex.